# Set up configuration to Access amazon order from seller account

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to set .config.inc.php of MarketplaceWebServiceOrders library that I used to access order of amazon seller account.

Here is my config.inc.php file setting

```
   /************************************************************************
* REQUIRED
*
* All MWS requests must contain a User-Agent header. The application
* name and version defined below are used in creating this value.
***********************************************************************/
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'MarketplaceWebServiceOrders');
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '2013-09-01');
```

After figure out these setting I got error

```
Caught Exception: Resource / is not found on this server. API Section is missing or you have provided an invalid operation name. Response Status Code: 404 Error Code: InvalidAddress Error Type: Sender Request ID: 47e5f613-5913-48bb-ac9e-cb00871b36af XML: Sender InvalidAddress Resource / is not found on this server. API Section is missing or you have provided an invalid operation name. 47e5f613-5913-48bb-ac9e-cb00871b36af ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: 47e5f613-5913-48bb-ac9e-cb00871b36af, ResponseContext: 6qut/Q5rGI/7Wa0eutUnNK1+b/1rvHSojYBvlGThEd1wAGdfEtnpP2vbs28T0GNpF9uG82O0/9kq 93XeUIb9Tw==, Timestamp: 2015-09-15T12:47:19.924Z, Quota Max: , Quota Remaining: , Quota Resets At:
```

Here GetOrderSample.php file code for service url. Which I have done already.

```
// More endpoints are listed in the MWS Developer Guide
// North America:
$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
// Europe
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
// Japan
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Orders/2013-09-01";
// China
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com.cn/Orders/2013-09-01";


 $config = array (
    'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
    'ProxyHost' => null,
    'ProxyPort' => -1,
    'ProxyUsername' => null,
    'ProxyPassword' => null,
    'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
    );

 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caught Exception: Resource / is not found on this server.
```

This is telling you that the problem is with the path. It's not being able to find that.

Are you sure that the class you're trying to use is in the right path? Most classes that you need to run the samples are in the "Model" folder.

I mean to say, if you take the sample out of the sample folder and put it elsewhere, it won't be able to find classes in the "Model" folder.

An easy fix to test it is to put everything you downloaded from the MWS site into your web directory and just edit the config file. It should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php guy, but I don't see where you're setting up the access keys, merchant id, marketplace id, and most importantly the serviceURL. The 404 error is the first clue meaning it can't find the service.  Download the [PHP client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html/181-6356767-7255165) which has everything you need to get started.

Comment: Yes I downloaded this library and worked on it. There is config.inc.php file under src folder there are configuration  of access key, secret key, application name and version, merchant id and marketplace id. I used all values but not sure about application name and version that these will be. Due to some security reason can't paste other values. But surely I did use other required value.

Comment: the application name and version don't matter.  I usually forget to even change these from the defaults.  You're getting a 404, so it's not even reaching Amazon.  Make sure you un-comment the serviceUrl from the sample files.  I'm looking at GetOrderSample.php and they have the serviceUrl commented out.  I am in North America, so I use that URL.  You can use a tool such as Fiddler to see the request and see what might be missing.

Comment: I edit my question . Please check my GetOrderSample.php which have code for service url.

Comment: it seems my credential have some problem so I got an error message
Caught Exception: Access denied Response Status Code: 401 Error Code: AccessDenied Error Type: Sender Request ID

Comment: Do you have an idea.  How to authorized seller account credentials. I'm sure credentials are correct but there is some problem in authorization